# RegexpTokenize Japanese sentences - python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm trying to split the japanese sentences up using RegexpTokenizer but it is returning null sets. can someone tell me why? and how to get split the japanese sentences up?

```
#!/usr/bin/python  # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import nltk
import os, sys, re, glob
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

jp_sent_tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(u'[^ 「」!?。．）]*[!?。]')

print jp_sent_tokenizer.tokenize ('の各宣言を実行しておく必要があることに注意しよう。これ以下の節では、各スクリプト例の前にこれらがすでに宣言されていることを前提とする。')
```

the output to the above code is

```
[]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're just missing a unicode **u**:

```
print jp_sent_tokenizer.tokenize (u'の各宣言を実行しておく必要があることに注意しよう。これ以下の節では、各スクリプト例の前にこれらがすでに宣言されていることを前提とする。')
```

Comment: thanks aab!! i was silly and i even tried unicode ('の各宣言を実行しておく...', 'utf-8') then print. putting the u there is much easier!!!